# regex split with non-capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match for html tagnames (eg. div in < div > ), and then split the string at the position of the match.

```js
var str = '&lt;div&gt; div';
var regex = /(?:&lt;)(\w*)(?=&gt;)?/g;
var arr = str.split(regex);
console.log(arr);
//result:   ["", "div", "&gt; div"]
//expected: ["&lt;", "&gt; div"]
```

However, the "&lt ;" gets lost by doing this, and also I want the div inside of the < and > removed. How can I achieve it?

This one also doesn't work, because then the "fake-div" at the end of the string would also be splitted, even though it is not within < and >:

```js
var str = '&lt;div&gt; div';
var regex = /(?:&lt;)(\w*)(?=&gt;)?/g;
var match = regex.exec(str);
var arr = match.input.split(match[1]);
console.log(arr);
//result:   ["&lt;", "&gt; ", ""]
//expected: ["&lt;", "&gt; div"]
```

Comment: Maybe replace it: `var str = '&lt;div&gt; div';var regex = /&lt;.*?&gt;\s*/g;var arr = str.replace(regex, "");`

Comment: well that is not a generic solution anymore to search for the tag name and split the string at that position. the given str was just an example

Comment: Parsing html with regex is a bad choice, use a html parser instead

Answer (score 0):

One of the closest you might get if you want to only use a single regex is:

```
var regex = /\b(?:\w+)(?=&gt;)/gi;
'&lt;div&gt; div'.split(regex);//["&lt;", "&gt; div"]
```

It gives the expected behavior but the obvious problem with this one is that it does not check preceding `&lt;`. And javascript does not natively support lookbehind.

A better approach might be to separate `&lt;` and `&gt;` and then combine them:

```
var str = '&lt;div&gt; div';
var ltRgx = /(?:\s|\b|^)(?=&lt)/gi;
var gtRgx = /\b(?:\w+)(?=&gt;)/gi;
var result = str.split(ltRgx).map(function(d,i){
    return d.split(gtRgx)
}).reduce(function(ac,d){
    return ac.concat(d);
});
console.log(result);//["&lt;", "&gt; div"]
/*Another example*/
str = '&lt;div&gt; &lt;img&gt; div';
result = str.split(ltRgx).map(function(d,i){
    return d.split(gtRgx)
}).reduce(function(ac,d){
    return ac.concat(d);
});
console.log(result);//["&lt;", "&gt;", "&lt;", "&gt; div"]
```